# Array based queue implementation with C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I implemented a queue that holds elements on an array as underlying data type:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace mine {
template <std::semiregular T, std::size_t N> class queue {
public:
  using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
  using const_value_type = std::add_const_t<value_type>;

  using reference_type = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<value_type>;
  using const_reference_type = std::add_const_t<reference_type>;

  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using const_size_type = std::add_const_t<size_type>;

  void enqueue(const value_type val) {
    if (current_size == N) {
      throw std::overflow_error("queue overflowed.");
    }

    if (current_size == 0) {
      m_head = m_tail = 0;
    }

    m_tail = current_size;
    m_data[current_size++] = val;
  }

  value_type dequeue() {
    if (current_size == 0) {
      m_head = m_tail = 0;
      throw std::underflow_error("queue underflowed.");
    }

    --current_size;

    auto ret = m_data[m_head];
    m_data[m_head] = T{};
    ++m_head;
    return ret;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] reference_type head() { return m_data[m_head]; }
  [[nodiscard]] const_reference_type head() const { return m_data[m_head]; }

  [[nodiscard]] reference_type tail() { return m_data[m_tail]; }
  [[nodiscard]] const_reference_type tail() const { return m_data[m_tail]; }

  [[nodiscard]] bool empty() noexcept { return current_size == 0; }
  [[nodiscard]] const bool empty() const noexcept { return current_size == 0; }

  [[nodiscard]] size_type size() noexcept { return current_size; }
  [[nodiscard]] const size_type size() const noexcept { return current_size; }

private:
  size_type m_head = 0;
  size_type m_tail = 0;
  int current_size = 0;
  value_type m_data[N]{};
};

}
```

And I wonder about the possible blunders, what is missing and how to make it better in general. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked how to make the queue better in general, so I’m going to go in a completely different direction from the other reviews, and answer that question specifically.

## Don’t abuse the standard library

The `enqueue()`/`push()` function throws `std::overflow_error` if the queue is full, and `dequeue()`/`pop()` throws `std::underflow_error` if the queue is empty. The problem with this is: that is *not* what those exceptions mean.

`std::overflow_error` and `std::underflow_error` are *supposed* to signal arithmetic errors—the overflow/underflow of values when doing numeric computations. If I tried to push a value into a queue and got a `std::overflow_error` thrown in my face, my response would be a flabbergasted: “What the *hell*? Did this queue just blow past `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` while trying to calculate its new size? Does it have some weird internal bug?”

Abusing existing standard exceptions because they just happen to have a name that sorta-kinda works in this case is a terrible idea. Either use the *correct* standard exceptions for the situation (for example, trying to push when the queue is full might warrant a `std::length_error`) or, much better, make specific exceptions for the specific errors. You could (and should) derive them from the standard exceptions where possible—in these cases, `std::logic_error` seems like a logical base:

```cpp
class queue_is_full : public std::logic_error
{
public:
  queue_is_full() :
    std::logic_error{"failed attempt to push to full queue"}
  {}
};

class queue_is_empty : public std::logic_error
{
public:
  queue_is_empty() :
    std::logic_error{"failed attempt to pop from empty queue"}
  {}
};
```

Or you could just throw a `std::logic_error`. This doesn’t really seem like a situation where specialized exceptions are necessary, because it’s not something that should ever happen. It’s trivial to not pop from an empty queue, or not push to a full queue, so it’s not like you should ever expect that to happen in well-written code.

## Ease up on the restrictions

You constrain the types that can be put in the queue using the `std::semiregular` concept. Is that really necessary? Is there a reason I shouldn’t be allowed to store, say, `unique_ptr`’s in a queue?

What do you *really* need for types in a queue? Well, as I see it, all you really need is for it to be copyable *OR* movable, so it can be copied/moved into and out of the queue. And you might not even need that with a slightly different interface. For example, if you had `emplace()`, then a value could theoretically be enqueued in-place—no copying or moving required at all. And if you had a way to pop that didn’t return the popped value—maybe spelled `drop()` or `ignore()`—then you could even dequeue without moving or copying (just destructing).

Now, `std::semiregular` implies not only copyable, but also default-constructible… which you really *shouldn’t* need for a queue at all. But we’ll cross that bridge shortly.

At the bare minimum, you should at least allow for noncopyable, move-only types. Because why not, right? You’d only need to change like two lines of code to do moves instead of copies in `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`, and use a requires clause instead of a concept directly:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
requires std::default_initializable<T> and (std::copyable<T> or std::movable<T>)
class queue
{
  // ...
```

## A more honest interface

The biggest issue I’d have with this queue is that it’s dishonest about its state. By that I mean, for example, if I create queue with `auto q = mine::queue<T, 10>{};`, then when `q.empty()` returns `true`… the queue is not really empty. There are actually 10 `T`’s in it!

Granted, I can’t actually get at those 10 `T`’s without some skullduggery… but they’re there. If `T` is some type that registers itself in some registry on construction, or has some static counter counting instances, I’m going to be baffled about where all these extra `T` objects are.

More honest implementations of `empty()` and `size()` might look more like:

```cpp
constexpr auto empty() const noexcept { return false; }
constexpr auto size() const noexcept { return N; }
```

Except that’s also somewhat misleading, because `q.empty()` would be `true` and `q.size()` would be 10… but when I do `dequeue()`/`pop()`… I get an exception because there’s supposedly nothing there.

I don’t have a solution to this quagmire (other than what I recommend about avoiding unnecessary constructions below). It would probably require additional or differently-named member functions, and probably giving up all hope of conforming to the standard container concepts.

## Avoid unnecessary constructions

The *real* biggest issue with this queue—the cause of the problem above—is that it initializes an array full of default-constructed `T`’s as an “empty” queue. That’s pretty weird; I’d expect an empty queue to have zero `T`’s in it… not several that just happen to be hidden from me.

Consider this implementation instead (neither tested, nor particularly well-thought-out; don’t trust it for anything but illustration):

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class queue
{
  static_assert(N != 0);

  std::array<std::optional<T>, N> m_data = {};
  std::size_t m_head = 0;
  std::size_t m_tail = 0;

public:
  template <typename... Args>
  requires std::constructible_from<T, Args...>
  auto emplace(Args&&... args) -> void
  {
    if (size() == N)
      throw std::logic_error{"queue is full"};

    // Don't update m_tail until the push succeeds, just in case of exception.
    //
    // The tail might be past-the-end (if the head is 0 and the queue is
    // full). To deal with this, we use the modulo operator (saves us a
    // conditional branch).
    auto index = m_tail % N;

    m_data[index].emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    m_tail = ++index;
  }

  auto push(T const& t) -> void
  {
    emplace(t);
  }

  auto push(T&& t) -> void
  {
    emplace(std::move(t));
  }

  auto pop() -> T
  {
    if (empty())
      throw std::logic_error{"queue is empty"};

    auto result = *std::move(m_data[m_head]);
    m_data[m_head].reset();

    // Advance the head. If it's past-the-end, wrap it around.
    m_head = (++m_head) % N;

    return result;
  }

  auto clear() noexcept -> void
  {
    for (auto&& t : m_data)
      t.reset();

    m_head = 0;
    m_tail = 0;
  }

  constexpr auto empty() const noexcept -> bool
  {
    // If the head and the tail are the same, then the queue is either empty
    // or full. The difference can be detected by seeing if the head optional
    // has a value or not.
    return m_head == (m_tail % N) and not m_data[m_head].has_value();
  }

  constexpr auto size() const noexcept -> std::size_t
  {
    // If the tail is greater than the head, then the size is simply the
    // distance between them.
    //
    // However, if the tail is less than the head, then the size is the
    // number of items between the head and the end of the array, plus the
    // number of items between the start of the array and the tail.
    //
    // (You could rewrite this to avoid the conditional, if you like, but I'd
    // leave that to the compiler.)
    if (m_tail >= m_head)
      return m_tail - m_head;
    else
      return (N - m_head) + m_tail;
  }

  constexpr auto max_size() const noexcept -> std::size_t { return N; }
};
```

When this queue is constructed, even though its size is statically-determined and there is no dynamic allocation, it’s still “empty” in that there are no `T` objects in it… just `N` value-less `std::optional`’s. As you push stuff, those `optional`s will contain those values… as you pop stuff, they become value-less again.

You could also do it better, with less wasted memory, and entirely `constexpr`†, by using an array of uninitialized memory, and `std::aligned_storage` or the equivalent, and `std::construct_at()`/`std::destruct_at()`. This would be *much* more complicated to do, but would probably be worth it. You’d need the `current_size` member again, but that’s one extra `std::size_t` in the queue class versus an extra `bool` for every element of the queue, so you’ll almost certainly save a *lot* of space for large queues. [The cppreference page on `std::aligned_storage` has a sample implementation of a static vector you could use as a base for this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) (though you should use `std::construct_at()`/`std::destruct_at()` rather than placement new and so on).

† (Presumably C++23? will have a fully-`constexpr` `std::optional`. But for now, you’d have to roll your own.)

Answer (score 7):

## Avoid unnecessary copies

`enqueue()` takes its parameter by value, which means the caller has to make a copy. Then it has to store that value in the array, making another copy. You can avoid copies by replacing the function that takes a value with two overloads, one for `const` references and one for rvalue references:

```
void enqueue(const_reference_type val) {
    // same as before
    ...
}

void enqueue(value_type &&val) {
    // mostly the same
    ...
    // but now we move:
    data[current_size++] = std::move(val);
}
```

The first version will make just one copy, the second one will use move assignment, which might avoid an expensive copy.

Similarly, `dequeue()` makes a copy. You can avoid this by splitting this function in two; one that returns a reference to the head element so the caller can read it without having to copy it, and another function that just removes the head element. You already have a `head()`, so then just modify `dequeue()` to be:

```
void dequeue() {
    // mostly the same as before, except without returning anything
    ...
}
```

This is also why `std::queue` provides a separate `front()` and `pop()` function. Also, doing it this way makes the requirements for `T` less strict; it now only requires it to be `std::default_constructible` and `std::movable`.

## Make it look like `std::queue`

Programming is much easier if everything has a similar interface. Consider renaming your member functions to match that of `std::queue`:

- `enqueue()` -> `push()`
- `dequeue()` -> `pop()`
- `head()` -> `front()`
- `tail()` -> `back()`

You could also add `emplace()` and `swap()` to make it almost a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Any tip on how to implement `swap()`? Because I need to swap the private variables as well. Maybe I could write a getter for the `m_data`, (like the `data()` on `std::vector`) to access but it would probably be nonsensical to have accessors for `m_head` and `m_tail` which are just a index values.

Comment: If you make it a member function it has access to `private` variables, if you make it an out-of-class function you should make it a `friend` of your `class queue`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695548/public-friend-swap-member-function) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

### Make your typedefs more similar to Standard Library types

There is no need for `const_size_type` or `const_value_type`; if the user wanted them they could simply use `const mine::queue::value_type` or the like—as, in fact, you do.

The standard library containers use `reference` and `const_reference`, not `reference_type` and `const_reference_type`. I would use the former set for consistency.

I wouldn't do `using value_type = std::remove_cv_t<T>;`. `T` cannot have top-level `const`, since then it wouldn't fulfil the requirements for `semiregular`. The only purpose then is to strip top-level `volatile`, which is of dubious benefit for the additional semantic burden.

### Don't define a non-`const` `size()` or `empty()` overload

The idea that calling `queue.size()` on a mutable queue potentially modifies it is... worrying. I would remove this overload entirely: remember that `const` member functions can be called on non-`const` objects, though not the other way around.

For the `const` overload you should return `size_type`, not `const size_type`. Although there is no functional difference in this case, returning by `const` value is typically discouraged, as for class types it can inhibit moving. (The fact that there is no functional difference for primitive types is probably a case for avoiding the `const` in `const size_type` in and of itself, too.)

All of the above applies to `empty()` as well.

### Make the type of `current_size` consistent

Currently your `current_size` variable is of type `int`, but everywhere you use it where you would otherwise expect to be using `size_type`. This is problematic, because `signed` types (like `int`) and `unsigned` types (like `std::size_t`) have different behaviour and can cause some odd issues when mixed.

In addition, on many systems `sizeof(std::size_t) > sizeof(int)`. This means that if the size of the array grows too large your `current_size` value will overflow, causing undefined behaviour.

As you are using `std::size_t`/`size_type` everywhere else here, you should make `current_size` `size_type` as well.

### Include (only) what you use

Your class does not appear to use anything from `<cassert>` or `<iostream>`. As such, you should remove those headers, to potentially improve compile times.